# Has anyone had any success brewing 11.5l in a 30l container?

Tags: first-time-brewer, brewing

I am keen to start home brewing but I don't want to make 23l of beer at a time. I'd like to brew smaller batches of different beers.

I have looked at the starter brewery kits available locally and they are all 30l containers for brewing 23l.

I have spoken to a brew master and he assured me it is possible to brew half, say 11.5l in a 30l container but oxidation and temperature are very tricky to get right.

Has anyone successfully brewed 11.5l in a 30l container and if so what brands did you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I brew 12.5L batches in 30L plastic fermenters.  Have done 15 batches or so without any issue.  The "fermenters" are generic 30L water containers from various hardware stores.

Comment: Thanks mate, what brands do you use?

Comment: The blue plastic water cubes from Bunnings in Australia.  No idea what brand they are.

Comment: Sorry I meant what brand of beer do you brew like Coopers or Mangrove Jacks. Thanks

Comment: Oh sorry, I do all grain BIAB in a 20L stockpot on my stovetop.  I've only done one pre-hopped brew, a "toucan" brew with a can of Coopers Dark Ale and Coopers Stout and a kilo of dark DME.  It was pretty awesome too, my dad is at me to do another batch (he drank half the first one).